# How to fetch the user ids from twitter using Twython based on a search string

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

I need to fetch the user IDs or user names from twitter who tweeted on a particular string (i.e., their tweet should contain that particular string EX:- Cricket, Tennis etc.). I am using Twython for that. I only know that we could fetch tweets using:
**twitter.search(q='cricket', count=100)**
and then loop through these fetched tweets and get user names which is tedious. Is this the only solution or is there any other so that I could get the user names directly without fetching the tweets?

Comment: if it's too tedious, maybe you should write a python script that does it for you :)